# Fixed column when vertically scrolling. Unfixed when horizontally scrolling. Pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a centered page with two columns filling the window height. The **left column** is **fixed**, so it is always visible when scrolling. The **right column** wraps the page content and will be usually larger than the left column.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="col1">
    <p>Fixed column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <p>Content column</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: fuchsia;
}

.col2 {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background: cyan;
}
```

When the browser window is narrower than the page width (300px in this example), a horizontal scrollbar will appear, and the **fixed column** will keep fixed and fly over the **content column**. I want to **avoid this**.

Can I achieve this vertical-only fixing with pure CSS (no Javascript)?

See the [full example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4bMVGUa9kIfDMWEc7QJ7).

**Clarification:** the vertical scrollbar must be the **window scrollbar**, not an inner scrollbar in `.col2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case you need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) or twitter [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Actually, I'm using both media queries and Bootstrap, but they can't solve this concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/4r4uG/)**

css

```
.col1 {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: fuchsia;
    z-index: 1; /* z-index lower than than .col2 */
}
.col2 {
    position: relative; /* position needed for z-index to work */
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background: cyan;
    z-index: 2; /* z-index higher than than .col1 */
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the "fixed" column issue, it just makes the fluid column visible at all times.

Comment: so how do you want it to behave?

Comment: What he wants to achieve is that the left column loses its fixed state when scrolling horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the CSS property `z-index:-1;` to the fixed column `.col1`, It will do the trick

Comment: Then, it flies under the .col2. I want .col1 to keep in its "absolute" position.

Comment: So what you want is a scroll bar only on .col2 right ?

Comment: I want to set a page minimum width (e.g., 920px). Under that width, a horizontal scrollbar will be shown and then the fixed column can overlap the content column.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with absolute positioning and overflow on the .col2 container only. This way you still have your fixed column on vertical scroll but not on horizontal scroll.

### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/85fyC/

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.main-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: fuchsia;
}

.col2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.col2 .inner {
    background: cyan;
}

.col2 .inner p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: It forces the vertical scrollbar to be in the .col2 and not in the window. I'd like to use the window scrollbar, like in Facebook. It is not compatible with your suggestion, but thank you anyway ;)

Comment: I know that it does but you are asking for a CSS only solution -- you might be willing to accept a compromise or fall back to JS instead.