# How do I make one column unmoveable while scrolling down?

Tags: html, css

I have these 2 columns:
[image: example]

If I scroll down on my html page, I want only the second column to scroll down, the left one should always be frozen.

Could someone help? This has to be done only in html.
Thanks!

Comment: You may find a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115340/fixed-column-when-vertically-scrolling-unfixed-when-horizontally-scrolling-pur

Answer (score 0):

You would use `position: fixed`. Then put all your content in the second column. See example below:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<body class="grid">
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  <p>
  This is the content for this section! :D
  </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey there’s a lot of ways to do this simple task but I’ll try and be as straightforward as possible.

In your JavaScript html, (I use Sumblime)

```
<div id=“Column1”> 
<p><strong>Column 1</strong></p></div>
```

Now I will open CSS in Visual Studio Code,

```
div#Column1 {
Background-color: rgb (0,0,0) 
font-family: ‘Roboto Mono’, monospace; 
float: left; 
border-radius 22;
position: absolute; 
right: 22%;

}
```

The ‘position’ method is used in CSS for positioning elements. In this case absolute can be used to make the position of the div for your column more static.

Be very very careful with it though!

Comment: "Be very very careful with it though!". You may elaborate on that; what are the pitfalls?

Comment: Please check the syntax of your CSS and what is 'Javascript HTML'? I think you may need to give more of the HTML context for your answer because I don't understand how making something position absolute stops it being scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use `position: sticky;` See my example:

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  gap: 15px;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
 }

.sticky p {
   font-size: 35px; 
   padding: 15px;
}
 
.content-block {
   width: 100%;
   height: 1000px;
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="sticky"> 
    <p>sticky on screen</p>
  </div>
   <div class="content-block"> 
    
  </div>
</div>
```